# Proof problem..

Tags: analysis

If p1,p2,p3,... is a non-decreasing sequence and there is a point x that is greater than every point of the sequence, then the sequence converges to some point.

So far I have gathered I need to use the completeness axiom which states if M is a point set and there is a point to the right of every point of M, then there is either a right-most point of M or a first point to the right of M.

However I am stuck on actually proving this. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That is called Weierstrass Monotone Convergence Theorem: if $(x_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers such that is montononically increasing [resp. monotonically decreasing] and bounded above [resp. bounded below] then $(x_n)$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim x_n=\sup\{x_n :n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ [resp. $\lim x_n =\inf\{x_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$].

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like the [Monotone Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem)